# foreach inside wordpress plugin class

Tags: php, wordpress

I have run into a slight issue when creating a `Wordpress` plugin. The plugin is class based and the problem appears to be with the `foreach` call within a function. The `foreach` call is iterating through an array and adding options to Wordpress using the options api. Any help getting this to work correctly would be appreciated.

**The Array**

```
$settings = array();
$settings['version'] = '0.1';
$settings['release'] = 'development';
$settings['license_accepted'] = 'false';
```

**The Function**

```
public function settings($action) {
        $supported_actions = array('install', 'update', 'uninstall');
        if (in_array($action, $supported_actions) == true) {
            foreach($settings as $setting => $value) {
                $current = 'plugin_'.$setting;
                if ($action == 'install') {
                    add_option($current, $value, null, true);
                }
                if ($action == 'update') {
                    update_option($current, $value, null, true);
                }
                if ($action == 'uninstall') {
                    delete_option($current);
                }
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
}
```

**The Problem**

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bring the `$settings` variable inside the function scope. You can do that by using a argument:

```
$settings = array(...);
$pluginClass->settings($action, $settings);
```

Or use Dependency Injection (I prefer), but I think that is to difficult for you and the plugin.

Comment: What do you mean it's too difficult for me, i tried your solution previously to posting this and it just returns "The plugin generated 398 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin." on activation but it works, any ideas on getting this error removed?.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the `$settings` array declared? it's most likely out of scope.

if you do a `var_dump($settings);` before the `foreach` you will get null.